# Can't read "length" propery on a variable that I know is a string (javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently working on a program in node, and part of my code looks like this:

```js
function interpretRange(num, shorthand) {
  let shorthandLength = shorthand.length
  console.log(typeof num);
  console.log(num.length);
  ...
```

When I run this code, passing `'1'` as the argument for `num`, I see the following in my console:

```
string
1
undefined
/Users/username/Documents/10. Programming/problem 4.js:78
  console.log(num.length);
                 ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Any idea why this error could be happening? As you can see, i checked for the type of `num` and it's a string. And then when I print `num` to the console it works and prints `1` which is correct.

However, for some reason I'm still getting the type error (even after the value was printed to the console).

**Edit: Full Code Here:**

The error happens at `num.length`

```js
function completeNumbers(shorthand) {
  let ranges = shorthand.split(', ');
  let longHand = [];
  ranges.forEach(range => { 
    let interpreted = [];
    let expanded = [];
    range.split(/[-:..]/g)
         .reduce((curr, shorthand) => { // What hapens if it's one number
           interpreted.push([curr, interpretRange(curr, shorthand)])
         })
    console.log(interpreted);
    interpreted.forEach(range => expanded.push(expandList(range)))
    console.log(expanded)
  })
}

function interpretRange(num, shorthand) {
  let shorthandLength = shorthand.length
  let baseNum = num.length === shorthand.length ? '0' : num.slice(0, -shorthandLength)
  let compareNum = num.slice(-shorthandLength);
  if (parseInt(shorthand) <= parseInt(compareNum)) {
    return String(parseInt(baseNum) + 1) + shorthand;
  } else {
    return baseNum + shorthand;
  }
};


completeNumbers("1:5:2, 3"); // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ... 12
```

Comment: can you reproduce this ?

Comment: It should work, can you add the next line of code?

Comment: function interpretRange(num = "", shorthand) { did this work ?

Comment: your function runs twice. First time with string '1' but second time with undefined.

Comment: Please add a [minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: If you notice, there are three lines. the first two are the type and length of the string, the second one are the type and length of undefined. `typeof undefined == undefined`, and undefined doesn't have properties

Comment: Ah, you're right, looks like it is running twice — I think that is the issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you don't return anything from the reduce, so the second iteration will have `undefined` as `previousValue` of the reduce function. That's why you're seeing this error (take a look at the doc of [Reduce Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce))

I don't know what you want to do actually but you have to return something inside the reduce function (according to what you want to do) or consider using `map` or simply a classic for loop